# Get UINavigationBar landscape height while device is in portrait

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

I have a simple question: I want to find out the height of a `UINavigationBar` in landscape while my device is in portrait. Is this possible and if so, how?

Some background:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[navBar sizeToFit];

NSLog(@"navBar: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(navBar.frame));
```

This returns the correct height **for the current device orientation**, for example `44`. That means that `UINavigationBar`'s `sizeToFit` method must somehow look at the current device orientation. Is there any way to get find out **what the height would be** in landscape without going to landscape?

Comment: It would help to know why you need to know this?

Comment: @maddy It's a theoretical problem. I basically just wonder if it is possible somehow.

Comment: @rmaddy I need the exact thing as well. In my case I am implemeting a custom `navigationItem.titleview` which needs to be configured differently for different `navigationBar` sizes(orientations). `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration` is deprecated and `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` shows the old orientations size not the upcoming ones.. can you offer an idea for this simple purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is one possible solution that works:

```
@interface TestVC : UIViewController
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIInterfaceOrientationMask orientationMask;
@end

@implementation TestVC
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return _orientationMask;
}
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)getNavigationBarHeight:(id)sender {
    TestVC *vc = [[TestVC alloc] init];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        vc.orientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    } else {
        vc.orientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
        UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        [navBar sizeToFit];

        NSLog(@"navBar frame in 'opposite' orientation: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(navBar.frame));

    }];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not grab and set that information in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation. By overriding this method you should be able to get the info you desire prior to the view being shown.

In other words, don't worry about it until you are actually in the process of changing your orientation.

[willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:)

Comment: That doesn't work. Querying the height in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` gives you the portrait height because it is called **before** the rotation and subsequent height-change has taken place.

Comment: From Apple doc: By the time this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property is already set to the new orientation, and the bounds of the view have been changed. Thus, you can perform any additional layout required by your views in this method.

Comment: Ah! My bad! You are right! I was thinking of willRotateTo... But still an actual rotation will have to be triggered. I was wondering how to do it from portrait without any rotation at all.